# La suma de las columnas de un schema no da lo mismo resultado dos veces

Tags: mysql, sql

Hice una tabla `shares` en la que inserté la suma de las columnas de otra tabla `communities`:

```
CREATE TABLE communities
    (`community_id` int, `shares_copylink` int, `shares_email` int, `shares_facebook` int, `shares_messenger` int, `shares_pinterest` int, `shares_twitter` int, `shares_whatsapp` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO communities
    (`community_id`, `shares_copylink`, `shares_email`, `shares_facebook`, `shares_messenger`, `shares_pinterest`, `shares_twitter`, `shares_whatsapp`)
VALUES
    (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (2, 2, 2, 196, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (3, 8, 20, 0, 8, 0, 0, 12),
    (6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (7, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (8, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
    (9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (12, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1),
    (14, 1, 1, 11, 0, 0, 0, 3),
    (16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (59, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (61, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (62, 2, 3, 28, 0, 0, 0, 9),
    (65, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (67, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (68, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (69, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (70, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (71, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (72, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (73, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (74, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (75, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (76, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (77, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (78, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (79, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (80, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (81, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (82, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (83, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (85, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (86, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (87, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (88, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (89, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (90, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (91, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (93, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (94, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (95, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (96, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (97, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (98, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (103, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (104, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4),
    (105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (107, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (109, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (110, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (111, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (142, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (145, 0, 1, 39, 1, 0, 0, 4),
    (146, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (147, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (148, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
;

CREATE TABLE shares (Date date, Shares int);

INSERT INTO
`shares` (`Date`, `Shares`)
SELECT
  CURDATE() as date,
  SUM(shares_copylink) + SUM(shares_email) + SUM(shares_facebook) + SUM(shares_messenger) + SUM(shares_pinterest) + SUM(shares_twitter) + SUM(shares_whatsapp) AS total
  FROM communities
```

El mismo día sumé estas columnas menos este resultado que acabo de insertar:

```
SELECT CURDATE(), (SUM(shares_copylink) + SUM(shares_email) + SUM(shares_facebook) + SUM(shares_messenger) + SUM(shares_pinterest) + SUM(shares_twitter) + SUM(shares_whatsapp) - SUM(`Shares`)) AS daily_shares FROM communities, shares
```

Y me da un resultado diferente a 0 lo cual es extraño.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/001e83/34/0

Utiliso MySQL 5.7

Comment: el problema es la forma en que estás haciendo `JOIN` entre las tablas...no hace mucho sentido que sea sin ninguna condición. Lo que está pasando es que básicamente está haciendo la suma de `Shares` completa para cada fila con datos de la tabla `communities`

Comment: ¡Ja, eso es muy raro! Gracias @Lamak ¿Y cómo se evita eso?

Comment: es que estás haciendo un producto cartesiando entre ambas tablas, porque no tienes una condición de `JOIN`. Se evita en primer lugar haciendo una correcta relación entre tablas, cómo quieres que esto funcione más adelante?, cuando haya más de un día de datos. Se puede solucionar para este caso específico, pero no hace mucho sentido

Comment: Creo que deberias parar de publicar preguntas por hoy... tomar aire.. tratar de entender que estas haciendo.. leer un poco de documentacion de sql.. estas cometiendo montones de errores basicos y con poco sentido porque tratas de llegar a algo sin tener en claro los pasos necesarios para llegar a eso... Y lo que es peor, no va a funcionar mañana....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Añadimos una línea con la suma de las shares de la primera tabla menos el resultado de la última línea

```
    c.execute("""
    INSERT INTO
    shares (`Date`, `Shares`)
    SELECT CURDATE(), 
        (
          (
          SELECT 
          (SUM(shares_copylink) 
          + SUM(shares_email)
          + SUM(shares_facebook) 
          + SUM(shares_messenger)
          + SUM(shares_pinterest) 
          + SUM(shares_twitter) 
          + SUM(shares_whatsapp)) as sumval
          FROM communities
          ) - SUM(`Shares`)
        ) AS daily_shares
        FROM shares 
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM shares);
    """)
```